# React Native: Checkbox List Structure

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

A `user` object has an array prop `schools` that references one or more school objects. I would like to use a `<List>` with `<CheckBox>` to mutate the `schools` array.

I load the `user` object into the view, and I load the `listOfSchools` (from the application state) to generate the checkbox list:

```
<List data={listOfSchools} keyExtractor={ item=> item._id } renderItem={({item})=>renderItem(item)} />
```

The `renderItem` function:

```
const renderItem = (school) => {

    return <ListItem
        title={school.name}
        accessory={()=>renderAccessory(school)}
    />
};
```

The `renderAccessory` function:

```
const renderAccessory = (school) => {
    return <CheckBox checked={() => checkSchool(school._id)} onChange={()=>changeSchool(school._id)} />
}
```

The `checkSchool` function returns boolean on if the `school._id` is referenced in the `user.schools` array. The `changeSchool` function adds or removes the `school._id` from the `users.schools` array.

The `changeSchool` function:

```
const changeSchool = (schoolId) => {
    let checked = checkSchool(schoolId);
    if (!checked) {
        // add schoolId to user.schools
    } else {
        // remove schoolId from user.schools
    }
}
```

This drastically does not work. It appears that no matter what I use to mutate the state, the checkboxes never update, nor does the `user.schools` array mutate.

What is the proper way to structure such a design goal?

Comment: I assume you use React Native Elements. If that is the case `checked` needs to be a `boolean`

Comment: To clarify, I'm using ui-kitten, which seems to be mostly the same. onChange is an available prop. @CornelRaiu, `checkSchool` returns a boolean. Is that acceptable?

Comment: I see. I will have a look then

Comment: @CornelRaiu changing from `checked={() => checkSchool(school._id)}` to `checked={checked}` with  `const checked=checkSchool(school._id)}` has now allowed the checkboxes show in the ui.

Comment: so it works ok now? I was currently just updating my answer

Comment: It appears that this was the major issue, yes. If you post your answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you use UI Kitten, I can see that you got the `checked` prop value wrong for the `CheckBox` component.

[UI Kitten CheckBox reference](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/components/checkbox/api#checkbox)

The `checked` prop needs to be a `boolean` not a Callable as you have it there

I would try to change the code like this:

```
const renderAccessory = (school) => {
    const isChecked = checkSchool(school._id);
    return <CheckBox checked={isChecked} onChange={()=>changeSchool(school._id)} />
}
```

Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 0):

While trying various solutions i can conclude few things here:

- With the solution given by @Cornel Raiu the checked and unchecked flags are getting correctly calculated however, the display was not correct with the state of checked/unchecked
- I replaced Checkbox with Toggle, just to be sure that it works with iOS too
- PROBLEM that i faced still is that, even the State of item getting toggled is correctly populating it was getting reset
- The outside container of Toggles is List and ListItem,
- OBSERVATION is that the Press event on List was actually getting the Checkbox/Toggle into correct Display State...

SOLUTION:
After longer time of research and experiments I got my thing working with following approach -

- I maintained separate collection of Checked Items
- There is already a state of Collection of master items, as input to List
- Every time the Checkbox/Toggle is clicked, the master list of Data is cloned and copied back to its state
- This was triggering the slight re-render of component and thing is working as expected.

  ```
    const [cashTransactions, setCashTransactions] = useState([]); // master data
    const [selectedTransactions, setSelectedTransactions] = useState([]); // selected data
    const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => (
            <ListItem
              title={'('+item.id + ') ' + item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName}
              description={Moment(item.createdOn).format('yyyy-MM-DD hh:mm:ss')}
              accessoryLeft={selectedTransactions.includes(item.id) ? RadioOnIcon : RadioOffIcon}
              accessoryRight={() => checkBoxSpace(item)}
            />
          );


          const checkBoxSpace = (item) => {
            let itemChecked = selectedTransactions.includes(item.id);
            return (
              <View style={styles.actionContainer}>
                <Button size='tiny' status='basic' accessoryLeft={rupeeSymbol}>{item.amount}</Button>
                <Toggle checked={itemChecked} status='primary' size='small' onChange={checked => checkboxChecked(item, checked)}></Toggle>
              </View>
            )
          }


          const checkboxChecked = (item, checked) => {
            console.log('Item -' + item.id + ' ' + checked);
            if (checked) {
              if (!selectedTransactions.includes(item.id)) {
                selectedTransactions.push(item.id);
              }
            } else {
              if (selectedTransactions.includes(item.id)) {
                selectedTransactions.pop(item.id);
              }
            }
            console.log('selectedTransactions ' + JSON.stringify(selectedTransactions));
            // This is the thing i applied to get it done.
            const cloned = [...cashTransactions];
            setCashTransactions(cloned);
          }

                 // View
                  <List
                      style={styles.container}
                      data={cashTransactions}
                      renderItem={renderItem}
                    />
  ```

Comment: I have used UI-Kitten Library